# programmatically resize button

Tags: android, android-button

I have created button programmatically in following way :

```
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Previous");
    setContentView(button);
```

I am getting button but full screen occupied. How to resize it and place it as per my need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your OnCreate method:

```
LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);

                Button button = new Button(this);
                button.setText("Previous");
                button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                layout.addView(button);
                setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 1):

full screen occupied because you `setContentView` the `button`.

if what you want to do is resizing `View` in **android**. use `LayoutParams`. for example :

```
button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

doing that will resize the button to fit the text `"Previous"`.

ok, you can try this [tutorial.](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/)

Comment: do you have `activity_main.xml`? if yes, then set your view there. and add the `button` to a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

Comment: added a basic android layout tutorial link for you.